# Fit a plot in a div's max height

Tags: javascript, html, css, plotly

I am trying a plot in a `div` using `plotly.js` which is a bit large in height. I want to fit it to div's height. If I use

```
<div id="plotDiv"></div>
```

and

```
var trace1 = {
            x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
            y: [20, 14, 23],
            name: 'SF Zoo',
            type: 'bar'
        };

        var trace2 = {
            x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
            y: [12, 18, 29],
            name: 'LA Zoo',
            type: 'bar'
        };

        var data = [trace1, trace2];

        var layout = {
            autosize:true,
            barmode: 'stack',
            xaxis: {
                tickangle: -45
            },
        };

        Plotly.newPlot('plotDiv', data, layout);
```

The plot is a bit large in height, so i put a `max-height` in `div`, this way :

`<div id="plotDiv" style="max-height:300px"></div>`

But this doesn't fit the plot in the div, and hides some of the plot. How to fit the complete plot in the div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by someone, (who had deleted his answer later on, before I could try and accept his answer), following the link here: [example](https://www.codeseek.co/plotly/responsive-fluid-layout-example-using-plotly-js-wKpPvj), 
I was able to resize the plot, :

```
var approved = {
                x: approvedX,
                y: approvedY,
                name: 'Approved',
                type: 'bar'
            };

            var unApproved = {
                x: unApprovedX,
                y: unApprovedY,
                name: 'UnApproved',
                type: 'bar'
            };

            var data = [approved, unApproved];

            var layout = {
                barmode: 'stack',
                xaxis: {
                    tickangle: -20
                },
                // title: 'Applications Comparison'
            };
            // Plotly.newPlot('plotDiv', data, layout);

            var d3 = Plotly.d3;

            var HEIGHT_IN_PERCENT_OF_PARENT = 80;

            var gd3 = d3.select('#plot2').append('div').style({
                 height: HEIGHT_IN_PERCENT_OF_PARENT + 'vh',
                'margin-top': 0 + 'vh',
                'margin-bottom': 10 + 'vh'
            });

            var gd = gd3.node();
            Plotly.plot(gd, data, layout);
            window.onresize = function() {
                Plotly.Plots.resize(gd);
            };
```

where `approvedX, approvedY, unApprovedX, unApprovedY` are lists.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a new div around the #plotdiv. Try out the following code.

```
<div style="max-height:300px">
    <div id="plotDiv" style="width:100%">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IS the width the right size? if only the height is going out of visible area after trying this, you can set both width and height to auto of #plotDiv

Comment: The width is fine.. Did you mean this? <div id="plotDiv" style="width:auto; height:auto">, this also didnt help.